# AppFabric Cache - Performance

Tags: c#, wcf, appfabric

I have developed a RESTful `WCF` service (`WebHttpBinding`), which is an AppFabric Cache client. I ran a performance test using jMeter. The test plan contained one operation in the service, which will be called in 100 concurrent threads.

However, I noticed that after running the test, `the first 20 to 30 threads are taking considerable amount of time to get the response (say 10-15 seconds)` and then all the other remaining threads will complete their execution in 2-3 seconds with AppFabric Cache related code turned on. Whenever I comment the AppFabric related code, it works just fine. Please note that I use only **Get**, no **Put**.

My service has the below configurations as t AppFabric:

```
<dataCacheClient requestTimeout="60000" channelOpenTimeout="15000" maxConnectionsToServer="2">
    <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="NotificationBased" ttlValue="300000" objectCount="100000" />
    <clientNotification pollInterval="10" maxQueueLength="100000" />
    <hosts>
      <host name="**********" cachePort="*******" />      
    </hosts>
    <securityProperties mode="Transport" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
    <transportProperties connectionBufferSize="131072" maxBufferPoolSize="268435456" maxBufferSize="8388608" maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000" receiveTimeout="600000" />
  </dataCacheClient>
```

Could someone please give some pointers as to what is causing this initial delay?

Answer (score 0):

If you do performance test you have to start with a warmup period. In this period you allow the application to do startup, and fill all caches. After the startup period you can test the application for real life prefomance.

In practice you start you application and run a few minutes without measuring the performance. Then you start your test and measure the performance. You will see that there is no startup delay at the begining of your test.

Comment: I am warming up the application before I start the performance test. Before running the test, I have a GET operation which I invoke using the browser. It is after that, I run the test.

Comment: But is your warm up 100 threads? The cache's thread pool needs warming up too. It takes a couple seconds of "being out of threads" before the pool will start to create and add new threads. It sounds like that delay might be what you are seeing.